# Magento 2 Installation fails at 27%

Tags: magento2

I have this exception when running the installation for Magento 2. Couldn't find further information on how to fix this anywhere, error thrown was not very clear either. Anyone has any ideas? This happens after it says 'Running schema recurring...'

Using Magento EE 2.2.3 on Ubuntu, with Nginx

```
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
[ERROR] LogicException: Request schema definition for topic "shared.catalog.product.price.updated" should reference existing service class. Given "Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Api\Data\OperationInterface" in /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Validator.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(204): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Validator->validateRequestSchemaType('Magento\\Asynchr...', 'shared.catalog....')
#1 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(111): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->extractTopicRequestSchema(Object(DOMElement))
#2 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(84): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->extractTopics(Object(DOMDocument))
#3 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(171): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->convert(Object(DOMDocument))
...
```

Comment: Helps to know the exact version, and OS stack details.

Comment: Also how are you installing? Composer? I am not familiar with `Magento_Amqp`

Comment: which magento 2  exactly version are you installing and how are you installing and which OS are you using ?

Comment: Just increase the **`php execution time`** & the **`php memory_limit`** of your server it will get installed.

Comment: Hi, i just updated my question with more details